# ¿Cómo controlar los tiempos de un ciclo for?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un ciclo `for`, tengo un array con unos datos y debo enviarlos a un Ajax para una api y almacenar esos datos, el problema trascurre en que los ciclos van tan rápido que no se logran almacenar todos los datos.

Quisiera saber si digamos que en el array tengo 8 elementos, como hacer que cada ciclo al llegar a la última línea, demore unos 3 segundos mas para pasar al siguiente ciclo

Es decir, arranca el ciclo `for` en 0, ejecuta sus líneas y en la última línea haga una pausa de 3 segundos, pasado esos 3 segundos corre el ciclo con el valor 1, y así sucesivamente.

```
for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j=j+2){
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "idplato": array[j],
    "idmenu": idmenu,
    "precio": array[(j+1)]
  });
  var url = 'PlatoxMenu/Insertar';
  var settings = {
    "url": $('#urlwebapi').val()+""+url,
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": data,
  };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

  });
  setTimeout(almacenar, 2000);
}
```

Tengo esto pero no me sirve.

Comment: No entiendo tu esquema, `array[j]` tiene el idPlato ??? y el elemento siguiente tiene el precio???

Comment: Lo podrías lograr con el uso de asincronía y promesas

Comment: es un array que en una posicion tiene un id seguido de un precio

Comment: digamos arreglo = [1,3000,2,5000,3,7000]

Comment: lo intente de muchas formas asicronico pero me arrojaa el mismo resultado

Comment: A ver... me imagino que todo el `for` está dentro de una función, ¿es así?, puedes convertirla asíncrona colocando `async function myFunction() {...}`. Ahora borra las últimas 4 líneas del `for`... luego crea un bloque `try / catch`, en el `try` ejecuta tu petición Ajax colocando `await $.ajax(settings);`, luego esperas a que se resuelva la petición pasando los 3 segundos para que continúe el siguiente bucle, colocando `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));`, prueba así y me comentas.

Comment: Si la cantidad de datos no es significativamente  grande, no seria prudente/conveniente enviar todo en una sola petición?

Comment: pues si Marcos, tienes razon, igual Cris gracias